# Remove callback not working in Handler

Tags: android, android-handler, android-runonuithread

I have Handler.I call my function every 10 second.Code working perfect,but i can't stop handler.This is my source code

```
handler=new Handler();
handler.post(runnable);
public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        myFunction(position);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,10000);
    }
};
public void myFunction(int position)
{
    if(position>10)
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}
```

I can call myfunction every 10 second,but i can't stop handler.Ho i can solve my problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "stopping handler"? Handler does not "run", it handles tasks given to him. Can you explain in a little more detail what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `myFunction` removes the callback, then you still call `handler.postDelayed` to schedule a new one.  There are plenty of ways to refactor this.  For example:

```
handler=new Handler();
handler.post(runnable);
public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean reschedule = myFunction(position);
        if(reschedule) {
            handler.postDelayed(runnable,10000);
        }
    }
};
public boolean myFunction(int position)
{
    if(position>10) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You don't have to remove callbacks on the handler because a new one will not be scheduled in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You remove callback in myFunction but you postDelayed again when myFunction returns, just invert lines inside run()

```
@Override
    public void run() {       
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,10000);
        myFunction(position);
    }
```

Comment: I"d suggest returning a boolean from myFunction and rescheduling based on that return value.